# Formatting with tr::before

Tags: css

https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#lefthandheader

I've got a sortable table via the above link, that is alternately striped. I've tried appending the left-hand header, and it's...not co-operating.

Using that CSS code leads to the numbers being top-aligned and having the same background colour as the page, instead of the same background colour as the row:

```
table.sortable tbody {
counter-reset: sortabletablescope;
}
table.sortable thead tr::before {
     content: "";
    display: table-cell;
}
table.sortable tbody tr::before {
    content: counter(sortabletablescope);
    counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Changing it to this:

```
table.sortable.stripes tbody td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(sortabletablescope);
    counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

Fixes the background issue but still doesn't vertically center the numbers...and if the left-hand cell contains enough text it actually overlaps the numbers now (although that text appears to be bottom-aligned, so it's all legible, but it just looks awful).

Other table-related CSS:

```
table.sortable.stripes tbody {
counter-reset: sortabletablescope;
}
table.sortable.stripes thead tr::before {
    content: "";
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: central;
}
table.sortable.stripes tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background: #666;
}
table.sortable.stripes tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {
  background:#555;
}table.sortable thead {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:#000;
}
table, td, th {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #FFFFFF;
vertical-align: central;
border-collapse: collapse;
text-align: center;
padding: 8px;
padding-right: 12px;
padding-left: 12px;
text-wrap:normal;
word-wrap:normal;
}
table {
     border: thin solid #FFF;
    background-color: #666;
}
td, th {
    border: none;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: Edited. Hopefully this is what you're after?

Comment: The `::before` pseudo element actually creates the element inside of its parent, before the content. So the one with `tr` works; you have created a new cell there to the left of the existing cells. But the one with `td` does not: it creates a new cell inside the first cell (which functionally is similar to putting a whole table inside the first cell). If you give everything borders, you can quickly see what happens.

Comment: Why does the tr one not carry over the alternating background colours and central vertical alignment, though? The TD version is just a suggestion I found trying to Google the background/vert align issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To assign a background to everything in the tr, you can't use `table.sortable.stripes tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td`; this would target the `td` elements only. Assign it to the whole tr instead; using `table.sortable.stripes tbody tr:nth-child(2n)` for a selector.
2. If you change the `display` value of something to `table-cell`, that doesn't mean the other properties change to match. If you want the `::before` to behave exactly like a table cell, make sure the other properties match too. In other words, the styles you now assign to `td` should be assigned to `tr::before` too.
3. `vertical-align` has an error, its value should be `middle`.

So a simplified version of your code would look like this. (Note: HTML taken from the website you link to.)

```css
table.sortable.stripes tbody {
  counter-reset: sortabletablescope;
}

table.sortable.stripes tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #666;
}

table.sortable.stripes tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #555;
}

table {
  border: thin solid #FFF;
  background-color: #666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.sortable td, table.sortable tr::before {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-wrap: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  border: none;
  max-width: 250px;
}

table.sortable tbody tr::before {
  content: counter(sortabletablescope);
  counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="sortable stripes">
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>Methusaleh</td>     <td>969</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Elijah Snow</td>    <td>100</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Shirley Temple</td> <td> 10</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>George Burns</td>   <td> 91</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Mrs Robinson</td>   <td> 40</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cheers. Dreamweaver's autocomplete was "central", not "middle".

Comment: @koberulz Strange. `central` isn't even a value. You should report this as a bug.